# CentOs7 on VirtualBox: Can Ping IP Address But Not Website

Tags: linux, docker, centos, virtualbox, centos7

I made a CentOs7 virtual machine and tried to download Docker, but it gave me the following error:

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_64&repo=os&infra=vag error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed to connect to 0.0.12.134: Invalid argument"
```

After searching around, I found that the virtual machine could not ping any websites. Every time I used command `ping` to ping an website, it gave me the following error:

```
$ ping www.microsoft.com
connect: Invalid argument
```

For reference, I used NAT and host-only network in the VM.

```
$cat /etc/resolv.conf
generated by /usr/sbin/dhclient-script
nameserver 10.0.2.3
```

I guess it is a DNS problem, but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is the content of your /etc/resolv.conf ?

Comment: I updated above.

Comment: see if [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/453185/vagrant-virtualbox-dns-10-0-2-3-not-working) helps

Comment: it is better to look into VirtualBox **network settings**, and inside the VM there make sure you have access to **gateway** and it is more convenient to use **bridge** then **NAT** in network setting

Comment: Can you explain how I can set access to gateway? Do I change the settings in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-xxx? @ShakibaMoshiri

Comment: I did try that link before, but did not work. @jabbson

Comment: I resolved the problem by using bridge and change some settings in /etc/resolv.conf. Thank you all!